# Centering graph in Shiny tabBox

Tags: shiny, plotly, shiny-server, shinydashboard, r-plotly

I don't seem able to centre my pie chart in the middle of my tabBox. Here is some fake data:

```
Source = c("LinkedIn", "Google", "Indeed", "Friend", "Past Presentation")
Number = c(35,22,29,12,19)

Source = data.frame(Source, Number)
```

And the code to the plot:

```
barSource = plot_ly(Source, labels = ~Source, values = ~Number, type = 'pie', 
                    textposition = 'inside',
                    textinfo = 'label+percent',
                    insidetextfont = list(color = "#FFFFFF"),
                    hoverinfo = 'none', 
                    marker = list(colors = c(orange, light_blue, dark_blue,grey, 'rgba(238,118,0,.7)', 'rgba(114,147,203, 0.7)'),
                                line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1))) %>% 
                    layout(
                      title = "",
                      width = 650, 
                      height = 650,
                      xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                      yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)) %>% 
                    config(displayModeBar = F)
```

Here is the code to the tabbox in the UI

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    type="text/css",
    "#Education img, #Gender img, #Country img, #Source img {
        width: 60%;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }"
  )),
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "demog", height = "800px", width = "800px",
              tabPanel("Source", barSource)
  )
))
```

Currently, this is what it looks like:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a "cleaner" solution, but you could solve the issue with fluidRows:

```
tabsetPanel(
    id = "demog", 
    height = "800px", 
    width = "800px",
    tabPanel("Source", 
             fluidRow(column(4),
                      column(4,barSource),
                      column(4)
                     ) # end of fluidRow
             ) # end of tabPanel
) # end of tabsetPanel
```